# SQL - How I can sum more rows into only one by article?

Tags: sql

Here is the picture what is the problem exactly.
I want to sum overed_qty into one row by order and article, and that's my confusion.

[image]

```
 -- Insert statements for procedure here    
    SELECT table_PrintJob.order_name, table_PrintJob.article_name, table_Orders.qty AS order_qty, 
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY table_PrintJob.order_name,table_PrintJob.article_name) > 1                                                  
        THEN SUM(table_PrintJob.qty * table_PrintJob.qty_operation) - MIN(SUM(table_PrintJob.qty * table_PrintJob.qty_operation)) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY table_PrintJob.order_name, table_PrintJob.article_name)                         
        ELSE SUM(table_PrintJob.qty * table_PrintJob.qty_operation) END) AS overed_pieces,                    
        SUM(table_PrintJob.repaired) AS repaired_qty
        FROM table_PrintJob 
        INNER JOIN  table_Orders On table_PrintJob.order_name = table_Orders.name
        WHERE table_PrintJob.date_time BETWEEN @start_time AND @end_time 
        GROUP BY table_PrintJob.order_name, 
        table_PrintJob.article_name,
        table_Orders.qty, 
        table_PrintJob.operation
        ORDER BY table_PrintJob.order_name
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using CDBMS - comlumnar database - that's standard.

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Expected result is the only group of repeat order, article and overed_pieces. So if i have ord1, art 1, 5 and ord1, art 1, 10 i need 15 for that order and article. I think the virtual table is okay. That i'll load the same data into table and read the final result to the user with the group by system.

Comment: Then why is this tagged for [[tag:sql-server]]?

Comment: This seems like a simple SUM / GROUP BY situation. SELECT order_name,  article_name, SUM(overed_qty) GROUP BY order_name, article_name. Maybe I am missing one of your requirements. Sorry if that is the case.If you need one row with all articles in a single column, a CTE or FOR XML is the ticket.

Comment: You must take the minimal value of one operation by the article and generate over qty by other operations. So it's not only the simple sum/group by situation.

Answer (score 0):

So i'm found the solution:

```
SELECT * INTO #tmpTable
FROM (
-- Insert statements for procedure here 
SELECT table_PrintJob.order_name, table_PrintJob.article_name, table_Orders.qty AS order_qty, 
   (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY table_PrintJob.order_name,table_PrintJob.article_name) > 1                                                  
    THEN SUM(table_PrintJob.qty * table_PrintJob.qty_operation) - MIN(SUM(table_PrintJob.qty * table_PrintJob.qty_operation)) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY table_PrintJob.order_name, table_PrintJob.article_name)                         
    ELSE SUM(table_PrintJob.qty * table_PrintJob.qty_operation) END) AS overed_pieces,                    
    SUM(table_PrintJob.repaired) AS repaired_qty
    --INTO v_tx
    FROM table_PrintJob 
    INNER JOIN  table_Orders On table_PrintJob.order_name = table_Orders.name
    WHERE table_PrintJob.date_time BETWEEN @start_time AND @end_time 
    GROUP BY table_PrintJob.order_name, 
    table_PrintJob.article_name,
    table_Orders.qty, 
    table_PrintJob.operation
    --ORDER BY table_PrintJob.order_name
    ) AS x

    select order_name,
    article_name,
    order_qty,
    sum(#tmpTable.overed_pieces),
    sum(#tmpTable.repaired_qty)
    from #tmpTable
    --INNER JOIN  table_Orders On v_tx.order_name = table_Orders.name
    group by order_name,
    article_name,
    #tmpTable.order_qty
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server I would recommend using a CTE rather than populating temp tables if you are only going to query from it once- saves time building and populating it

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have been a little confused, but now is okay.